# How to set a custom NSTextStorage to a UITextView object created from a storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextstorage

I want to set a custom `NSTextStorage` to a `UITextView` object created from a storyboard. If it's really needed I can consider subclassing of `UITextView`.

(I know if I created a `UITextView` object from the code I would be able to use a `init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?)` constructor.)

Swift is preferable.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem possible even if you subclass UITextView because storyboard instantiates with init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder). You might be able to reverse engineer the decoding process, but I doubt it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
final class SendTextViewController: BaseViewController {
    @IBOutlet private var textView: UITextView!
    private var textStorage = MentionTextStorage()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.textStorage.removeLayoutManager(textView.layoutManager)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(textView.layoutManager)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by adding a `UITextView` subview to a `UIView` wrapper subclass that is instantiated from the storyboard. You can then add a getter on the view controller that returns the box's textView instance, so that you can assign yourself as the delegate, access properties etc...

Something like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet private weak var textViewBox: TextViewBox! // connected in storyboard

    var textView: UITextView! {
        return textViewBox?.textView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe I asked something else. Sorry.